# Ejecutar llamadas a un servicio en bucle

Tags: ios, swift3

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo :

```
for petition in petitions {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        EmailController.sharedInstance.sendPetitions(params: petition, completion: {
                            self.getPetitions()//Update the badge petitions
                        }, failure: { (errorCode, errorDescription) in

                        })
                    }
```

El problema es que claro se llaman a los servicios uno detras de otro aun que aun no haya obtenido respuesta , y lo que quiero es precisamente que no pase al siguiente item del bucle hasta que la llamada del servicio no haya dado respuesta , alguien se le ocurre alguna manera ? gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías tener un array de las peticiones e ir vaciándolo según se completan, a la vez que lanzas la siguiente petición.

```
var petitionsQueue: [Petition] = []
```

Setea tu array de peticiones de la manera que más te convenga. Y después desde dónde quieras empezar las llamadas al servicio llamas a la siguiente función:

```
func sendNextPetition() {
    if let nextPetition = self.petitionsQueue.first {
        EmailController.sharedInstance.sendPetitions(params: nextPetition, completion: {
        self.petitionsQueue.removeFirst()
        self.sendNextPetition()
        }, failure: { (errorCode, errorDescription) in

        })
    }
    else {
        print("todas las peticiones han sido procesadas")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto ocurre porque tu  `DispatchQueue` es asincrono, por lo tanto lo hace en segundo plano, puedes agregar

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync
```

Comment: Si yo tmbn intente hacer eso y hacer el update de la interfaz de manera asincrona pero tampoco funciona , por que las llamadas las hace una a una pero se hacen aun que no haya obtenido respuesta aún de la anterior.
Al final he hecho una ñapa haciendo un contador y contando el numero de respuestas obtenidas y si coincide con el numero de llamadas realizadas entonces ya oculto el spinner ... pero tiene que haber otra manera

Comment: pero si tu consulta al servidor ya es asincrona, porque haces el update de manera asincrona? Lo que entiendo es que quieres ejecutar una llamada a la funcion, 1 por 1, y la manera de hacerlo es como nte deje en mi respuesta, el update de la interfaz es totalmente distinto a la consulta a tu servicio

Comment: Pero quiero hacer la llamada y que hasta que no obtenga la respuesta no pase a la siguiente llamada , tanto haciendolo de manera sincrona como asincrona pasa a la siguiente llamada sin haber obtenido respuesta de la primera

Comment: puede que se genere un error al hacer la llamada, verificaste eso?

Comment: No el funcionamiento que hace es una llamada al servicio utilizando un completionBlock de respuesta , entonces va haciendo la llamada y pasa a la siguiente y las respuestas de estas llamadas van llegando en orden o no depende de si es asincrono o no pero eso es lo de menos la cosa es que me gustaria que no pasara a la siguiente llamada hasta que no obtengas respuesta , de esta manera haría (llamada-respuesta) (llamada - respuesta) y no (llamada-llamada) (respuesta-respuesta) como hacer ahora